# Is mapping beans with List of bean properties supported by model mapper?

Tags: java, modelmapper

I am trying to map two JavaBean structures (here simplified):

```
package foo;
public class Container {
    private List<Item> items;
    public List<Item> getItems() { return items; }
    public void setItems(List<Item> items) { this.items = items; }
}

public class Item {
    private String message;
    public String getMessage() { return message; }
    public void setMessage(String message) { this.message = message; }
}
```

In addition I have equal Beans with the same properties in package `bar` and do the mapping between the two like

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
bar.Container barContainer = mapper.map(fooContainer, bar.Container.class);
```

where the source `fooContainer` contains a list of items some of which have the property `message` set to a `String` and some of them have `null` as property value.

In the mapping result I discover that the list of `foo.Item` seems to be correctly mapped to a list of `bar.Item` also the first `message` properties are mapped correctly. But after the first item with a `null` value of the `message` property all `message` property values of hte following items are mapped to `null` regardless of the content of the source properties.

With debugging I found out why:
Once the destination property value is `null` the message property path is marked as shaded in MappingEngineImpl:207 and then ignored for the subsequent items in MappingEngineImpl:142.

Is this a bug of moddelmapper or do I have to configure modelmapper in another way to enable mapping of list of bean properties?

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It was indeed a bug which I just pushed a fix for over at github. You can grab the fixed build now or wait for the next release which I hope to get out in a few days.

Comment: 0.4.0, which includes the fix, has been released.

Comment: @Jonathan thanks I'll try it when I have to touch that project the next time ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitely looks like a bug to me. I actually encountered the very same issue with my own use of ModelMapper which is how I found this question.

Shading paths that are null seems dangerous since the same context is used to map other objects. I have taken this feature out and it seems to work as expected.

I created an issue on the ModelMapper page around this bug:
http://code.google.com/p/modelmapper/issues/detail?id=19

Also, I fixed the issue and posted it to GitHub. I have made a pull request and hopefully it will be incorporated into the next version of ModelMapper:
https://github.com/chrisdail/modelmapper

Comment: Thanks for your work! For now I had mapped the beans hardcoded but if your pull succeeds I'll try modelmapper again :)